# Getting Java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nettSocketTimeout Exception Read timedout

Tags: openrewrite

While using the below plugin on the project getting readTimedOut error. Even increased the maven heap to 16GB as well.

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <activeRecipes>
            <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2</recipe>
          </activeRecipes>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Seems like this recipe has multiple recipes and if we do one by one we can get some of things working. How can I do this completely and how to determine how much heap needed for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having trouble connecting to Maven Central as the recipes execute. Might there be any kind of network issues, or a proxy/mirror that get's in the way?

There's also a change in the works to set different timeouts, perhaps you'll want to keep an eye on this PR: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/pull/3951